# Example projects using Jasmine-Node and/or Jasmine client

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Are there any end user example projects that use best practices of javascript testing frameworks jasmine-node / jasmine. Something like a simple CRM, rss reader etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Diaspora project](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora), which [uses jasmine for testing](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/tree/master/spec/javascripts).

Answer (score 3):

Check out a demo I used in a presentation a few months back: https://github.com/mtscout6/javascript-testing-example

It's a simple To Do List demonstration.